# redirecting to subdomains without getting unusual traffic in apache2

Tags: apache2

i tried to redirect my site like
https://something.com/num1 into https://num1.something.com/
using something like this

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'something.com'"> Redirect "/home"
Redirect "/num1" "https://num1.something.com/"
</If>
```

but due to that, i think my recaptcha detects my redirection into an unusual traffic.is there a way to redirect it without being detected as unusual traffic?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that it happened due to ssl change to wildcard ssl. so it appears that i have to change the sitekey